# Silverlight--No changes possible

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-web-developer

I've just encountered a strange mistake in a Silverlight project I'm working on with Visual WebDeveloper Express. When I change the MainPage.xaml file the changes show up in the editor window and the project is compiled without problems. However during Debug Mode the website hasn't changed.

My goal was to implement a very simple image viewer for my father: One big image with a small progressbar below. It should be possible to set up a few images that are shown one after another in the huge image control. This is what I did.

1. I added two rows to the standard
   grid
2. I added a progressbar to one of the rows
3. I added an image control to the other row

So far everything went fine. Debugging showed an empty website with a small bar at the bottom.

1. I imported a test image and modified
   the source attribute of my image
   control

After some struggles with Visual WebDeveloper the image was accepted and could be seen in the editor's preview area.

1. I compiled the project and started debugging. There was no image on the website.

I don't know what's wrong with my project but the builds seem to have frozen. Just for fun I replaced the image with one giant button. Nothing happened. Compilation was performed without errors but on the website there was no button. After a few other simple tests I was sure: Changes don't apply anymore.
This is the compiler output, sorry but it's German :

> ------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: papa_images, Konfiguration: Debug Any
>   CPU ------   papa_images ->
>   K:\extharddrive\dokumente\workspace\papa_images\papa_images\Bin\Debug\papa_images.dll
>   Generierung des Anwendungsmanifests
>   starten   Es wurden keine Änderungen
>   ermittelt. Die Anwendungsmanifestdatei
>   ist auf dem neuesten Stand.
>   XAP-Verpackung starten   Es wurden
>   keine Änderungen ermittelt. Das
>   XAP-Paket ist auf dem neuesten Stand. 
>   Die Testseite wird erstellt.   Die
>   Testseite wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
>
> ## ========== Build: 1 erfolgreich oder aktuell, Fehler bei 0, 0 übersprungen

This is an English version of the last two lines

> Build: 1 successful or up to date,
>   error at 0, 0 skipped

What shall I do ?

Edit:

**I just made an interesting discovery:**

1. I switched the build mode to release
   and recompiled everything. --No
   changes
2. I closed my browser.
3. I switched the build mode back to
   debug and recompiled everything.
4. When I started debugging Firefox 4
   Beta 7 opened instead of Firefox
   3.6.1. This is strange because 3.6.1 is my standard browser.
5. The changes were applied.
6. I started editing this post using
   Firefox 3.6.1
7. I started debugging again. The
   updated website was shown in FireFox 3.6.1
8. I changed something in MainPage.xaml
   and compiled. As Firefox 3.6.1 was
   still open the website was opened
   with it. The new changes were not
   applied

Obviously Firefox 3.6.1 prevents proper rebuilding. Why ? @ Robaticus maybe you're right and Firefox does store the site in some kind of cache. However I'm not able to clear it : The button "delete chronic" is disabled because I'm always using private mode.

Edit 2:
Firefox 4 Beta 7 does the job. The changes are applied. Still I would like to know how to use Firefox 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tagging on to ChrisF, you may also want to explicitly clear your chache on your browser.  I've had that happen before, where the XAP file gets cached for some reason, and never appears to update.

Comment: I'm always using Firefox in private mode. There should be nothing stored in the cache.

Comment: @lhk - not Firefox's cache but the server's cache - C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files or C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files depending on your .NET version

Comment: How can I clear the servers cache ? I tried closing it and restarting the computer. It didn't work. Then I deleted my temporary files with CCleaner. Still there are no changes. Is it possible to tell Visual WebDeveloper Express to do the job for me ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the Silverlight xap file isn't being updated correctly in the ClientBin folder of your web site.

As a work around you could try deleting it before rebuilding and checking that your edits are indeed compiling.

The only thing I can think of that might prevent the xap file being updated is that it's still in use by the web service, but the message (as translated by Google so it's not 100% accurate) reads:

> Build started: Project: papa_images, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ papa_images -> C: \ extharddrive \ documents \ workspace \ papa_images \ papa_images \ Bin \ Debug \ papa_images.dll generate the application manifest, there were no changes identified start.
>   The application manifest file is up to date
>   Xap packaging, it does not start to change were identified.
>   The XAP package can be created on the date the test page.
>   The test page was successfully created.

which implies that there were no problems in that area.

Comment: I deleted it and rebuilded the project. Still there are no changes.

Answer (score 1):

Is Cassini running?  Look in the Notification Area (by the clock) for something called "ASP.NET Development Server."  Sometimes we have problems where we have to close that or it remembers what it was last showing.

You can just close it and run again

Comment: It was running but even after closing it and compiling everything again there were no changes. I restarted the computer and tried compiling again -- no changes