# MultiScaleImage is not visible

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-web-developer, deepzoom, multiscaleimage

1. I added a MultiScaleImage to my
   Silverlight project

   2. I created a deepzoom compatible
      Image with DeepZoomComposer
   3. I imported the image into my project and stored it in a folder named Source
   4. I set the Source attribute of the
      MultiScaleImage to
      "Source/dzc_output.xml"

So far everything worked just fine. In the editor's preview window the image was displayed properly. However during debugging there was no image. This has nothing to do with my other question regarding "frozen" builds in silverlight.

[Silverlight--No changes possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349040/silverlight-no-changes-possible)

I'm using Firefox 4 Beta 7 now and all changes to the project are applied. How can I make the display appear during debugging ? Did I miss something important ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use Firebug to check if your app can find (and download) the DeepZoom source. Then add a border around your DeepZoom control to check that it is correctly displayed (and if yes, where).

Comment: Firebug is not available for Firefox 4 Beta 7. The border is correctly displayed in the center of the screen. However there's neither the Multiscalimage nor a white gap in the border.